# Simple form validation

Tags: forms

I have a site with a simple contact form using ASP for customers to e-mail quote requests. However, I'm getting quite a few messages through with no contact information; I think people assume that their e-mail address is coming through automatically.

I'd like a simple way to make the e-mail and/or telephone number fields required, preferably so that the fields are highlighted as such if they're submitted without anything in them. I've Googled for this but they seem either too simple, diverting people to a separate page and requiring a 'back click', or incredibly complicated with massive reams of code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

You should use a combination of server-side validation as well as client-side (JavaScript) to ensure there are no security holes in your form.

For any specific coding examples, please direct the question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: JavaScript validation can fail if the user has disabled JavaScript in the browser. It can also fail if the browser fails to interpret the JavaScript correctly -- that is, if the JavaScript is not written to support a variety of browsers. So JavaScript validation *is* best from a user interface perspective, but server-side validation is safest from the standpoint of receiving data. Otherwise, you will be vulnerable to injection attacks, etc. In the case of email, an unvalidated address can be manipulated to case the server to send SPAM. Only server-side validation would prevent this.

Comment: @bogeymin - Cross-browser JavaScript support doesn't take too much trickery, although it can be a pain and also get pretty redundant. ElendilTheTall could use a combination of JavaScript and PHP validation to ensure a tight security net. If the user has JavaScript disabled, there are ways to check that and alert the user of the problem. It could potentially limit your user base, however many secure websites require JavaScript to be enabled for primary functionality.

Comment: What if the "user" is a robot designed to POST data directly to the server? Server-side validation is the only best practice to prevent abuse. It is misleading to say that javascript validation (by itself) "is the best".

Comment: @bogeymin - I agree, as I said a combination of both JavaScript (For ease of use for both the administrator and the user) as well as some kind of server-side (E.g. PHP, etc.) validation for "a tight security net."

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ASP form generators" that generate both server side and client side scripts.